# When allowed to start service not in foreground mode

Tags: java, android, android-service, illegalargumentexception

I want to start a service when the application has the first activity started. When all activities are stopped the service should be stopped too. I implemented this behavior using `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`.

It works fine, but sometimes I get `IllegalArgumentException` on `startService()` method.

When allowed to start service, not in foreground mode.

Comment: Use a Bounded Service instead.

Comment: It throw the exception because service is already running in the background .and you are forcing it to restart.

Comment: You can bind the service to the activity.

Comment: I need start the service when at least one activity is running, and destroy when all activities are stopped. Bounded service does not suited me.